# using Typeclasses on SparkTypes

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to use scala TypeClass on Spark Types, here is a small code snippet I wrote.

```
trait ThresholdMethods[A] {
    def applyThreshold(): Boolean
}

object ThresholdMethodsInstances {

    def thresholdMatcher[A](v:A)(implicit threshold: ThresholdMethods[A]):Boolean =
        threshold.applyThreshold()

        implicit val exactMatchThresholdStringType = new ThresholdMethods[StringType] {
        def applyThreshold(): Boolean = {
            print("string")
            true
        }
    }

    implicit val exactMatchThresholdNumericType = new ThresholdMethods[IntegerType] {
        def applyThreshold(): Boolean = {
            print("numeric")
            true
        }
    }
}

object Main{
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("ZenDataValidationLib").config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value")
            .master("local").getOrCreate()
        import spark.sqlContext.implicits._
        val df1 = Seq(
            ("2016-04-02", "14", "NULL", 9874, 880, "xyz"), ("2016-04-30", "14", "FR", 9875, 13,"xyz"), ("2017-06-10", "15", "PQR", 9867, 57721,"xyz")
        ).toDF("WEEK", "DIM1", "DIM2","T1","T2","T3")
        import ThresholdMethodsInstances._
        println(df1.schema("T1").dataType)
        ThresholdMethodsInstances.thresholdMatcher(df1.schema("T1").dataType)
    }
}
```

When I run this on my local intellij, following error is thrown

```
Error:(46, 51) could not find implicit value for parameter threshold: com.amazon.zen.datavalidation.activity.com.amazon.zen.datavalidation.activity.ThresholdMethods[org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataType]
        ThresholdMethodsInstances.thresholdMatcher(df1.schema("T1").dataType)

Error:(46, 51) not enough arguments for method thresholdMatcher: (implicit threshold: com.amazon.zen.datavalidation.activity.com.amazon.zen.datavalidation.activity.ThresholdMethods[org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataType])Boolean.
Unspecified value parameter threshold.
        ThresholdMethodsInstances.thresholdMatcher(df1.schema("T1").dataType)
```

I also tried the same things using String and Int and it worked perfectly fine. Can someone help me in doing this on SparkTypes ?

Answer (score 0):

Please note that `StructField.dataType` returns `DataType`, not a specific subclass and your code defines `implicit` `ThresholdMethods` only for `IntegerType` and `StringType`.

Because `implicit` resolution happens at compilation time there is not enough information for compile to determine the right instance, which would make the types match.

This would work if you'd (obviously you don't want that):

```
ThresholdMethodsInstances.thresholdMatcher(
  df1.schema("T1").dataType.asInstanceOf[IntegerType]
)
```

but in practice, you'll need something more explicit like pattern matching, not implicit argument.

You can also consider switching to strongly typed `Dataset`, which be a better choice here.

Comment: I tried to see schema of df1 and we have StringType and IntegerType defined there. Is there a way to abstract it out and use that implictly to type check?

Comment: `IntegerType` or `StringType` are subclases of `DataType`. But compiler cannot tell which one will be returned when `dataType` is called. That's why implicit substitution is not possible here.  So if the question is, if it possible to use the API you have now, the answer is (as far as I can tell) negative. `DataFrame` just doesn't carry all the required type information for that.